# p tag in button tag not allowed?

Tags: html

I have a `<button>` element and within it, a `<p>` element. The `<p>` element is used in combination with css, `margin-top`, in a class to vertical align the text within the button (the button has a specific height).

The html looks like this:

```
<button class="someClass">
    <img ... />
    <p class="anotherClass">Caption</p>
</button>
```

This works fine, the text is vertically aligned like it should be. However I get a warning inside visual studio 2012 saying:

> Element 'p' cannot be nested inside element 'button'.

---

**My questions:** why isn't the `<p>` element allowed inside a `<button>` element? And what is the alternative?

Comment: What version of visual studio are you using?

Comment: I am using version 2012.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

That is correct, it isn't allowed, because;

- The content model of [`button`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-button-element) element is [phrasing content](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#phrasing-content) (with no [interactive content](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#interactive-content) descendant).
- And the [`p`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-p-element) can only be used where [flow content](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#flow-content) is expected.

An alternative is getting rid of the `p` element, and instead using a `span` element with `display: block`:

```css
.anotherClass {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<button class="someClass">
  <img ... />
  <span class="anotherClass">Caption</span>
</button>
```

Comment: but I read on another topic on stackoverflow that span doesn't support margin-top. How do I center my text inside my button then?

Comment: @Cornelis That isn't `span`'s fault, the problem is that `margin-top` does not apply to inline elements. Then, just style it as a block.

Answer (score 3):

Generally you're not supposed to put block elements inside of inline elements.

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio is correct in this issue: no HTML specification allows `p` in `button`, not even the rather liberal [definition](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/the-button-element.html#the-button-element) in HTML5 CR.

However, browsers do not actually enforce this restriction (in the sense that they enforce e.g. the restriction that `span` cannot contain `p`: they implicitly close an open `span` element when they see a `<p>` tag). So your code “works”, though there is really no guarantee that it will keep working (or that it works on *all* browsers).

To make the code formally valid, replace the `p` element by a `span` element and style it. You might also put a `<br />` tag before it, to ensure a line break even when CSS is disabled. To set a top margin on it, make it a block or an inline block. Example:

```css
.anotherClass {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 1em;
}
```

```html
<button class="someClass">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/50" alt="Some text" /><br />
    <span class="anotherClass">Caption</span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the `p` and some other tags cannot be used within the `button` tag, the best workaround, as others have stated, is to use a styled `span` tag.

You treat the `button` tag "as if" it was a container `div` of your `span` tags within. That way, you can style your whole `button` however you want. In my example, I styled it with a simulated icon, title, description, and button within the button.

I'm adding a little extra styling and formatting for visual purposes, but yours can be as simple or complex as you want.

```css
/* CSS Styling and classes example */


/* style the main container */

button {
  background-color: transparent;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.2s;
  padding: 10px 15px;
}


/* what happens when you hover - optional */

button:hover {
  background-color: #efefef;
}


/* what happens when it's active - optional */

button.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}


/* global style for the contained span tags within */

button span {
  display: block;
  margin: 5px auto 10px;
}


/* individually styling the inner span tags by class identifiers */

button span.step {
  background: #c33;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 2px 0 0;
  font-size: 1.75em;
  font-weight: 600;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

button span.title {
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: 600;
}

button span.desc {
  font-size: 1.05em;
}

button span.btn {
  margin: 20px auto;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background: #c33;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!-- html code -->
<button class="customClass">
        <span class="step">1</span>
        <span class="title">Title</span>
        <span class="desc">My cool button description</span>
        <span class="btn">Click Here</span>
    </button>
```

Of course, you can modify, add and remove span elements as you see fit, including images.