# Custom figures inside a button

Tags: html, css, blazor-server-side

I'm trying to make a simple board game, where I have 2 dices, which is just a paragraph with borders and a coloured circle inside. You roll both dices at the same time, so I wanted to have them inside a button, so that when you click on the button it calls the `RollTheDice` function (I'm using Blazor Server Side).

This is what I have so far, which is actually working (ignoring the fact that everything gets a grey background because of the button):

```
<button @onclick="RollTheDice" style="margin: 0 auto; display: block">
    <span class="d-flex">
        <p style="border: 2px solid gray; border-radius: 10px; height: 100px; width: 100px; margin: 10px">
            <svg height="90" width="90" style="margin: 5px">
                <circle cx="45" cy="45" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" fill="@dices[0]" />
            </svg>
        </p>
        <p style="border: 2px solid gray; border-radius: 10px; height: 100px; width: 100px; margin: 10px">
            <svg height="90" width="90" style="margin: 5px">
                <circle cx="45" cy="45" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" fill="@dices[1]" />
            </svg>
        </p>
    </span>
</button>
```

However, it appears that putting paragraphs (`<p>`) inside a button is bad practice (as mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26002381/p-tag-in-button-tag-not-allowed)).

**So how do you make a button with some custom stuff inside, without violatin all these rules (it's not only `<p>` that isn't allowed)?**

*Note: I have also tried making it a `<div>` instead of a `<button>`, but then if you click the div "button" too fast repeatedly, you start marking other elements (like when you double click somewhere in a text).*

*Update: I have also tried making each dice an individual button, but then I get this weird glitch with a double when I click the dice:*

[image: the right button has a double edge]

Comment: If it's interactive, better to keep it a `<button />`, which is interactive by default, rather than trying to rebuild the wheel with a `<div />`.  A [`<span />`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span) element is considered phrasing content, so you could just put a `<span />` inside the button and use CSS to style it like a paragraph?

Comment: @AlexanderNied I tried `<span>` but struggled a bit with the dices being on top of each other (instead of next to each other). It might just be a question of configuring the `<button>` tag correctly though. I also tried making it a button per dice as mentioned in my update.