# How to access elements of a clicked button

Tags: javascript, html, css

New to programming, trying something out for a JS project.

I have three adjacent buttons with the following contents:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < plantButtons; i++) {
  document.querySelectorAll(".option")[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    // alert("Plant Button Clicked!");
    plantContainer.style.display = "none";
    plantView.style.display = "flex";
  });
}
```

```html
<a class="option flex-column">
    <img class="plant-img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50">
    <h3 class="plant-name">Cactus</h3>
    <p class="plant-desc">A hardy plant with low watering needs and high sun tolerance.</p>
</a>
<a class="option flex-column">
    <img class="plant-img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50">
    <h3 class="plant-name">Spider Plant</h3>
    <p class="plant-desc">A unique plant, adaptable to a variety of conditions.</p>
</a>
<a class="option flex-column">
    <img class="plant-img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50">
    <h3 class="plant-name">Boston Fern</h3>
    <p class="plant-desc">A luscious plant with particular requirements. </p>
</a>
```

When any of the buttons are clicked, they all vanish and a single display appears - in this case, it'll be for one of the three plants on the buttons.

I want to access information from the buttons to help populate the new display afterwards.  For example, if they click on the button with the picture of the cactus, I want the following display to have a heading "Cactus" without just hard coding the new header.

I'm not sure about the best way to tackle this, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There is nothing you've included that would make anything "_all vanish and a single display appears_". Please provide more detail and a [example].

Comment: [Buttons](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button) are [not allowed to contain block-level elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26002381/p-tag-in-button-tag-not-allowed) like headings and paragraphs.

Comment: As you can see from the output, the snippet above is incomplete. Please remedy that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As some comments are pointing out, you need to separate the block-level elements from your buttons. Anchor tags would be a better option. You could use those in combination with if statements, .innerHTML, and .onclick listeners to populate your new display depending on which anchor is clicked.

Comment: Wow, this worked! Thanks for taking the time to help out.