# Why does Chrome on desktop show fonts in different size to safari on iPhone7?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, google-chrome, safari

I've got a React app I've made for mobile devices, mainly phones. I'm viewing my app in Chrome on an iMac and Safari on an iPhone7 but the font sizes are different on each device!

I make the size of the Chrome window's overall content the same size as the viewable part of the iPhone screen simply by holding the phone up to the iMac and dragging the corner of the iMac Chrome browser window so that the dimensions of the window's overall content area are pretty much the same as those of the iPhone (302 x 444px, Chrome tells me).

The problem is that the font sizes in Chrome on the iMac are bigger than those in Safari on the iPhone.

How do I make them equal?

An example of text that suffers from this problem is the `<p>` in my custom-made buttons (which reads "Click me"). The CSS class for this `<p>` looks like this:

```
.myButtonTextStyle {
font-family: 'Xxxxxx'; //a font downloaded from Google and embedded in the style sheet
  font-size: 17px;
  line-height: 20px;
  font-weight: 200;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0px;
  margin:  0px;
                   }
```

But the text in the buttons looks far bigger in Chrome on the iMac than in Safari on the iPhone. I can't understand why they are not the same.

Also the `<div>`s that are the main part of my custom buttons look bigger in Chrome on the iMac than in Safari on the iPhone.

How can I ensure that the font size of text/ the size of a div I see in Chrome on the iMac matches what I see in Safari on the iPhone (or any mobile device made by any company)?

Comment: Please show the relevant HTML. It sounds from your description as though you have a p element within a button element. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26002381/p-tag-in-button-tag-not-allowed